# Linux: increment

Tags: linux, unix, sum, decimal, addition

I have 1.0.5. How can i increment to 1.0.6?

Tried this but it does not work.

```
echo 1.0.5 0.0.1 | awk '{sum=$1+$2; printf"%0.2f\n", sum }'
```

Comment: 1.0.5 is not a decimal number.   1.05 or 10.5 are decimal numbers.

Comment: Moreover what would you expect 1.0.9 + 0.0.1 to be (1.0.10 or 1.1.0)? Or 5.7.9 + 8.7.6 to be? Or 7.5 + 6.7?

Answer (score 2):

As @fpmurphy pointed out 1.0.5 is basically a string , you cannot parse it as a decimal.

Try splitting it and then increment it as follows :

```
echo 1.0.5 |cut -d'.' -f3 | awk '{sum=$1+1;printf"%s",sum}'
```

This increments the last part of the string.Append it to the first part to get the desired result.

Comment: Actually doesn't this just output '6' (not '1.0.6')? And if you put in "1.0.9" it outputs "10".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative reading of the problem to @Ramblers - this increments the number as if it were a dotless decimal:

```
echo 1.0.5 | perl -pe 's/\.//g;$_++;s/(\d)/$1./g;s/\.$/\n/;'
```

IE it will go

`1.0.5
...
1.0.9
1.1.0
...
1.9.9
2.0.0
...
9.9.9
1.0.0.0
1.0.0.1`

Let's break that perl apart:

```
perl -pe '     // Read each line of the input
s/\.//g;       // Remove dots
$_++;          // Increment number, dropping trailing \n
s/(\d)/$1./g;  // Replace each digit by that digit followed by a dot
s/\.$/\n/;     // Replace the trailing dot by a trailing \n
'              // Output the line (per -p)
```

Comment: I don't like it. You go from major version 9 to major version 1? Who are you, microsoft?

Comment: @glennjackman It goes from major version 9.9 to 1.0.0. As the question was fundamental ill-specified (see my comment on the question), it's difficult to know what the intention was.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of ruby to add each part of the version string:

```
ruby -e '
    version = ARGV.shift.split(".")
    increment = ARGV.shift.split(".")
    newver = version.zip(increment).map do |ary|
        ary.map {|elem| elem.to_i}
           .reduce(:+)
    end
    puts newver.join(".")
' 1.2.3  0.8.8
```

outputs

```
1.10.11
```

As an unreadable oneliner

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGV.shift.split(".").zip(ARGV.shift.split(".")).map {|a| a.map {|e| e.to_i}.reduce(:+)}.join(".")' 1.2.3 0.8.8
1.10.11
```

Answer (score 0):

For another way, you could use this...

```
$ echo 1.0.4 | awk -F '[/.]' '{n=$1$2$3; print n+1}' | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
1.0.5

$ echo 1.0.9 | awk -F '[/.]' '{n=$1$2$3; print n+1}' | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
1.1.0

$ echo 1.9.9 | awk -F '[/.]' '{n=$1$2$3; print n+1}' | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
2.0.0

$ echo 9.9.9 | awk -F '[/.]' '{n=$1$2$3; print n+1}' | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
1.0.0.0
```

> This doesn't work well if the version is such as below:

```
$ echo 9.19.8 | awk -F '[/.]' '{n=$1$2$3; print n+1}' | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
9.1.9.9
```

Hope it usefull..